# How to undo operations done in code? Method 'Undo' of object 'Application' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have two codes that depend on application events.

Code (1) `worksheet_SelectionChange` Insert Date by using Date Picker [Link](https://trevoreyre.com/portfolio/excel-datepicker/)

```vb
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
   If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M3:M100")) Is Nothing Then Call Basic_Calendar
End Sub
```

Code (2) `Worksheet_Change` Log changes of any cells of ActiveSheet and put in another sheet("Log").

**Error raised** : after inserting any value by using Date Picker

> Method 'Undo' of object '_Application' failed

on `Application.Undo` on Code (2).

I tried to add `If Target.Cells.CountLarge = 1` just below `worksheet_SelectionChange` event, but the same problem.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   'Log Changes of Current Sheet and put in Sheet("Log")

 Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue  'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = Sheets("Log")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AK:XFD")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'not doing anything if a cell in AK:XFD is changed
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    TgValue = ExtractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'Put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 
 Application.EnableEvents = False               'Avoide trigger the change event after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = ExtractData(Target)          'Define RangeValue
     PutDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet           'Put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
 
 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        columnHeader = Cells(1, Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Column).value
        rowHeader = Range("B" & Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row).value
        
        Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
            Array(UN, Now, rowHeader, columnHeader, TgValue(r)(0), RangeValues(r)(0))
    End If
 Next r
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
          
End Sub


Sub PutDataBack(arr, SH As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        SH.Range(El(1)).value = El(0)
    Next
End Sub


Function ExtractData(Rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, Count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(Rng.Cells.Count - 1)
    For Each a In Rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
        For i = 1 To a.Cells.Count
            arr(Count) = Array(a.Cells(i).value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): Count = Count + 1
        Next
    Next
    ExtractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: Link for the real file https://easyupload.io/qplh7l

Comment: Excel's _undo_ stack doesn't track operations carried by macros - in other words it's macros' job to track what they do and how to undo it. You can try storing `Target.Value` in a module variable in `SelectionChange`, and then you can assign the `Target.Value` its previously held value by assigning it to the value you stored when the cell was selected before its value was changed. Note that there are a number of caveats, notably involving clipboard / copy-paste operations which can alter a cell that wasn't necessarily selected first.

Comment: As @Mathieu Guindon stated, **undo does  not work for any change made by a macro**. A working solution cannot be supplied only adapting the code you show.  One or two `Public` variable should be added in the module where `Basic_Calendar` exists and used to keep the previous value and the fact that a change will be done using Date Picker... I will look into your workbook and try finding a solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please copy the next code instead of existing (in the module containing `Basic_Calendar`):

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public PrevVal As Variant, boolDate As Boolean
Sub Basic_Calendar()
    datevariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
    If datevariable <> 0 Then
        PrevVal = Selection.value: boolDate = True 'memorize the previous value
                                                   'and mark the case of Date Picker use
        Selection.value = datevariable
    End If
End Sub
```

Then use the next adapted `SelectionChange` event:

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M3:M100")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Basic_Calendar
  Else
        boolDate = False 'make it false to trigger the previous behavior in Worksheet_Change event
  End If
End Sub
```

and `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   'Log Changes of Current Sheet and put in Sheet("Log")
 Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue  'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = Sheets("Log")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AK:XFD")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'not doing anything if a cell in AK:XFD is changed
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    TgValue = ExtractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'Put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 
 Application.EnableEvents = False            'Avoid trigger the change event after UnDo
     If boolDate Then  '____________________________________________________________
        Dim prevTarget
        prevTarget = Target.value            'memorize the target value
        Target.value = PrevVal               'change the target value to the one before changing
        RangeValues = ExtractData(Target)    'extract data exactly as before
        Target.value = prevTarget            'set the last date
     Else                   '____________________________________________________________
        Application.Undo
        RangeValues = ExtractData(Target)    'Define RangeValue
        PutDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet     'Put back the changed data
     End If
     
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
 
 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        columnHeader = Cells(1, Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Column).value
        rowHeader = Range("B" & Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row).value
        
        Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
            Array(UN, Now, rowHeader, columnHeader, TgValue(r)(0), RangeValues(r)(0))
    End If
 Next r
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic          
 End Sub
```

Use the same existing functions (`ExtractData` and `PutDataBack`) and send some feedback after using it...

Comment: @Waleed78 Please download the updated workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/s3ymnz). The link will be valid for 7 days...

Comment: Excellent work , many great thank MR/FaneDuru.

Comment: I am afraid to tell you there are issues, If I deleted some cells on column M together on sheet "North", this action is not triggered on sheet "Log" at all.

Comment: @Waleed78 There is  no connection between what you say now and your previous question, I would say... Does the above event code exist in **sheet "North"** code module?

Comment: Actually the codes found  between event in sheet "North" and in module "Calendar".**to produce issue** use calendar to enter any value but not click outside Column *M* then delete these values again , then switch to sheet *Log* you will notice that no entries for deleted values !

Comment: If I should ask a new question , please advice ?

Comment: @Waleed78 I will leave my office in about 20, 30 minutes. If I will see it and have time to do something, I will try advising. If not, only after some hours, when I will be at home...

Comment: Kindly, when you have free time , could you check the issue ?

Comment: @Waleed78 What issue are you talking about? Is there a problem with the above code? Is it something else? If so, I need you to better define what "issue" does mean...

Comment: I posted a new question , Kindly help if you have free time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70475570/target-cells-not-triggered-by-event-worksheet-change-how-to-fix