# Target cells not triggered by event `Worksheet_Change`. How to fix?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below codes as the following:
`Code(1)@ Worksheet_SelectionChange` Insert Date by using Date Picker(calendar) on sheet "North"
**Column M**.
`Code(2) @ Worksheet_Change` of sheet **North** to Log changes of any cells and put in sheet("Log").
`Code(3)` in a separate module "Calendar" to initiate calendar

the codes works except in one condition
**Target cells not triggered by event `Worksheet_Change`**
**to produce issue** use calendar to enter any value but `not click outside Column M` then delete these values again , then switch to sheet "Log" you will notice that there are no entries for deleted values at all.
As always: any help will be appreciated.
(**Link** for the real file found in first comment)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M3:M100")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Basic_Calendar
  Else
        boolDate = False 'make it false to trigger the previous behavior in Worksheet_Change event
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   'Log Changes of Current Sheet and put in Sheet("Log")
 Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue  'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = Sheets("Log")
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AK:XFD")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'not doing anything if a cell in AK:XFD is changed
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    TgValue = ExtractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'Put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 
 Application.EnableEvents = False               'Avoide trigger the change event after UnDo
     If boolDate Then  '____________________________________________________________
        Dim prevTarget
        prevTarget = Target.value                'memorize the target value
        Target.value = PrevVal                     'change the target value to the one before changing
        RangeValues = ExtractData(Target)    'extract data exactly as before
        Target.value = prevTarget                'set the last date
     Else                   '____________________________________________________________
        Application.Undo
        RangeValues = ExtractData(Target)          'Define RangeValue
        PutDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet           'Put back the changed data
     End If
     
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
 
 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        columnHeader = Cells(1, Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Column).value
        rowHeader = Range("B" & Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row).value
        
        Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
            Array(UN, Now, rowHeader, columnHeader, TgValue(r)(0), RangeValues(r)(0))
    End If
 Next r
 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
          
 End Sub

Sub PutDataBack(arr, SH As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
    For Each El In arr
        SH.Range(El(1)).value = El(0)
    Next
End Sub
Function ExtractData(Rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, Count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(Rng.Cells.Count - 1)
    For Each a In Rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
            For i = 1 To a.Cells.Count
                arr(Count) = Array(a.Cells(i).value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): Count = Count + 1
            Next
      Next
    ExtractData = arr
End Function
```

' in a separate module "Calendar" to initiate calendar
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

```
Public PrevVal As Variant, boolDate As Boolean
Sub Basic_Calendar()
    Dim datevariable As Variant
    datevariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
    If datevariable <> 0 Then
        PrevVal = Selection.value: boolDate = True
        Selection.value = datevariable
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Link for the actual workbook https://easyupload.io/b7uc95

Comment: I cannot reproduce the scenario you mention in the question... I mean, even if I do not execute any click ("outside M:M", as you say, or anywhere else), the code line `If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select` make the cursor jumps outside the modified cell. In order to delete the value of a cell in M:M, when the calendar form appears, I simple close it, without selecting any date. Then, deleting the active cell value, the change is logged. Doesn't the cursor jump outside? If I did not understand well what you mean, please better clarify the circumstances when the problem appears.

Comment: @FaneDuru This is a screen recorder reproduce the scenario https://easyupload.io/k7i063

Comment: I tested this scenario and it works as it should. I do not understand what the meaning of word "again" from "I deleted values again". Do you try deleting them twice?

Comment: I mean by again that deleted after entered , I am using office 2016. It is strange that no issue with you after I showed you the screen recorder

Comment: I think the issue related to SelectionChange event

Comment: The scenario I tested is the next: Click in a cell on M:M column and insert a Date. Click again in another cell and insert another one. Then, press `Shift` and click in another cell of the same column, to select many cells and press `Delete`. The deletion is logged for all cells. Is is something I am missing? Working in Excel 365...

Comment: @FaneDuru Please,Test this scenario : after insert date on a cell on M:M then select this cell by mouse and close pop up calender Press `Delete on keyboard`

Comment: So I did it. I forget mentioning the calendar form closing. Do you have AnyDesk installed?

Comment: @FaneDuru no at all , this issue happens on my work PC and now on my laptop , But the same version of office 2016 installed on both.

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks for all your efforts , I will wait two days to start Bounty

Comment: If you install AnyDesk (on your laptop, it is free) and send me the ID in the next 10 to 15 minutes, I can connect to your system and see what happens, making some tests and running the event line by line...

Comment: Ok. I will install now , the workbook will be on my desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the solution allowing multiple cells entry from the Callendar, but also allowing multiple deletions, please adapt it in the next way:

1. Use this modified code in the module where `Basic_Calendar` `Sub` exists:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Public PrevVal(), boolDate As Boolean
Sub Basic_Calendar()
    Dim datevariable As Variant
    datevariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
    If datevariable <> 0 Then
        PrevVal = Selection.value: boolDate = True
        Selection.value = datevariable
    Else
        Erase PrevVal 'to identify the case of deletion        
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

If your installation/version is not deal with directly loading the array, please use the next version, which do it by iteration:

```
Sub Basic_Calendar()
    Dim datevariable As Variant
    datevariable = CalendarForm.GetDate
    If datevariable <> 0 Then
        Dim i As Long
        ReDim PrevVal(1 To Selection.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
        For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
            PrevVal(i, 1) = Selection.Cells(i).value
        Next i
        boolDate = True
        Selection.value = datevariable
    Else
        Erase PrevVal 'to identify the case of deletion
    End If
End Sub
```

2. Adapt this part of the `Worksheet_Change` event code in the next way:

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    If Not CBool(Not Not PrevVal) Then boolDate = False 'the new line checking if the multiple rows array is empty (or not)
    TgValue = ExtractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'Put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
```

The logic of the modification works as following:

a. When the Calendar form is called and it returns a Date, **in a multi rows range**, the delivered `datevariable` is dropped in the selected cells, and their previous value are loaded in `PrevVal()` array;

b. A change in Column "M:M" triggers the event and in case of `PrevVal()` not empty, it acts as usually for inserting Data (using the `PrevVal()` array elements instead of `UnDo`, which does not work for data added by code). In case of an empty array, it makes `boolDate = False`, switching the code to the clasic variant (able to use `UnDo`, because deletion has been done by the user)...

No need to check the code on another PC. It was a matter of solution logic starting from a wrong assumption and it cannot work differently than on your laptop.

Comment: I tested your answer , yes it fixed the issue of `Target cells not triggered` But unfortunately prevented end users to enter multi entries by Calendar in one shot , otherwise the bad error raised again `Method 'Undo' of object 'Application' failed`.I will be go to home after tomorrow , and will test on another PC with Office 2021 to check is these issues related to Office 2016 or not , and feed you back.

Comment: @Waleed78 I did not remember such a necessity. It only happened to cover it (using an array)... That's why I wrote above "the code was designed to work only for a single cell" and I tried solving . I will adapt it to accept multi entries by Calendar value. I have in mind erasing the `PrevVal` array in case of closing he Calendar form and then checking in the event if the array is empty (or not). I will adapt it in some minutes (I think...). The event should reach that code part **only for deletion**.

Comment: Good morning, I got error `type mismatch` on this line `  If Not CBool(Not Not PrevVal) Then boolDate = False`

Comment: Did you declare PrevVal() as I suggested?

Comment: Sorry , it was declared as variant. But after I corrected I got error `Type mismatch` when I use calander to set value on one cell , the error on this line `PrevVal = Selection.value: boolDate = True` on Calender module

Comment: As Variant, is default, even if you do not declare the type. Did you use parenthesis?

Comment: Yes , I used parenthesis

Comment: I do not have access at my laptop now. After more than an hour I will have and if you will be available for connection I will try that, to see what happening in your installation. It works on 365. In the meantime, please send AnyD II on my mail...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240448/discussion-between-waleed78-and-faneduru).

Comment: Many great thanks Mr/FaneDuru. I really happy for your keen and Patience to help me and other People on this community. All works excellent 

Comment: @Waleed78 I am not sure I can get you... Does the above code work, or the one posted in the chat room? If second option, I should adapt the answer here... If the first one, what wander did happen in order to make it working, since it was not working in the morning?

Comment: I am sorry for this confusion , your last code on our chat Room is the good one which fixed the issue. I wrote comment here , because I do not receive any notification when you write to me on chat Room.

Comment: @Waleed78 OK. Adapted the code with second version, too...